LWC Component in Flow Revisited Screen Values
I have a Flow LWC component with a few input fields. One of the input fields is always visible and the visibility of the other fields is dependent upon previous screen selections within the Flow. In order to maintain input values between next/previous screen navigation, I selected "Use values from when the user last visited this screen". But I want to have functionality similar to "Refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow" for the visibility variable.
This visibility variable is just a string that is either slds-show or slds-hide and then I'm applying that variable to the class
<lightning-layout class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-small">
        <lightning-input label="Always Visible Input 1" value={input1} type="number" size="12" onchange={handleInput1Change}></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-small" CLASS={VISBILITY}>
        <lightning-input label="Conditionally Visible Input 2" value={input2} type="number" size="12" onchange={handleInput2Change}></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>
</lightning-layout>

Is there a way I can maintain the input values from the last screen visit, but still have this visibility variable get updated upon navigation to the screen by referencing selected Flow inputs from previous screens? Or just forcing the single visibility variable's value to get reassessed (i.e. a display text of this visibility variable shows slds-hide while the retained value is slds-show)

Is this an input variable to your LWC flow screen component?  Is this similar to:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366796/flow-screen-component-lwc-how-to-maintain-internal-state-on-page-navigation-or

@NickC This has been the best solution so far, but it still leaves an issue. Using "Refresh inputs to incorporate changes elsewhere in the flow": If I enter the values in the screen, click next, then click previous, the values are maintained on this page. But if I enter the values, click previous, then click next, the values are cleared out. It solves the visibility, which is more important, but I'd also like to not lose previously entered data. Which is why I was hoping to use "Use values from when the user last visited this screen" with lwc logic to keep visibility updated
